# Why isn't my app on the list of apps to open pdf files only?

Tags: android

I have an pdf reader app that is designed to give selection option to open any pdf file in the system within application. I have referred the below link:
[Why isn't my app on the list of apps to open txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152838/why-isnt-my-app-on-the-list-of-apps-to-open-txt-file)
I just want my app to be on the list of opening only pdf files, but now my app is on the list for every type of files. I did have  , but I wonder if I should specify mimeType. What should I do to restrict my app to only appearing on list of opening pdf files?

Thanks in Advanced,
AA.

Comment: Hey Arushi .. Hope you got your solution here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055859/android-opening-pdf-isnt-working

Comment: Above code is not restricts my application to open only pdf file. My code. <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> <data android:scheme="file" /> <data android:mimeType="/" /> <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" /> </intent-filter> </activity> Opening all types of file. I want to open only pdf file through my application.Thanks.

Comment: okie,, Sorry for that.. I'm doing R&D for tht.

Answer (score 3):

I used to write a similar app. I posted my AndroidManifest.xml segment for your reference:

```
<activity
    android:name=".OpenFileActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
        </action>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
        </category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" >
        </category>

        <data
            android:mimeType="application/pdf"
            android:scheme="file" >
        </data>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
        </action>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
        </category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" >
        </category>

        <data
            android:mimeType="application/pdf"
            android:scheme="content" >
        </data>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
        </action>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
        </category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" >
        </category>

        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\.[pP][dD][fF]"
            android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Above code is not restricts my application to open only pdf file. My code. <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
           <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> <data android:scheme="file" />  <data android:mimeType="*/*" /> <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />  </intent-filter> </activity> Opening all types of file. I want to open only pdf file through my application.Thanks.

Comment: You may specify mimeType to "application/pdf".

Comment: I tried to change the mimeType from "*/*" to "application/pdf" but still text files also can open through my application.

Comment: Do you have other intent filter in Manifest file? I tried it on my samsung S4. It works well.

Comment: In my manifest launcher screen has intent filter as <activity
            android:name="com.scriptor.activities.ScriptorMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> and one intent filter from my activity i.e two filter in manifest.